# Change initial View Controller from AppDelegate after async request

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, appdelegate

I want to change the initial view controller when the user starts the app, but only after I get the information on which one to present, from the server.

It goes like this somewhat like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FirebaseManager.getUserProfile() { user in
       if user?.sports.count == 0 {  

       // present View Controller 1   

       } else {

       // present View Controller 2

       }
   }

   return true
}
```

After the call is made, I decide which VC to be shown, but, the problem is that `return true` is triggered synchronously at the start.

This results in an unpleasant user experience because it shows the initial storyboard (`Login.storyboard`, as configured in the `info.plist`) and only after the request has finished (after several seconds), it changes to the correct view controller. I want it to change directly to the view controller, without showing anything else before (even if it will required more waiting from the user).

How can I avoid this? What is the best practice when dealing with such a situation?

Comment: Show the splash VC till you get the response from the service. Create a new VC(which would be your initial VC) with Splash image as background and in viewDidLoad call the service method and navigate accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I know that it will work and I will be looking for other solutions as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Firebase remote config parameters. It stores your data locally. And you can remotely manage it.

Or store value in `UserDefaults` of `FirebaseManager.getUserProfile()` beforehand.

Comment: I can store in UserDefaults, but I will have to have a separated UserDefault for each user that signs in, which doesn't look too good. But thanks for telling me about the Firebase remote config parameters, which I didn't know about.